# Find which TTY device connected over USB

Tags: usb, serial-port

I am doing android development. The adb ppp command to switch back to the USB cable instead of tcp/ip says it needs the tty as a parameter.

I have googled for this and found lots of references to solutions that don't work. A lot of those point to ttyUSB0, which doesn't seem to exist on my system.

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. How can I find my tty for my android phone?

Thanks.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options beside [`dmesg` in the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/803863/26246)

### Diff of `/dev/` listing

1. Store list of devices before plugging in Android

   ```
   ls /dev/ > dev_list_1.txt
   ```
2. Then run this after you plug it

   ```
   ls /dev/ | diff --suppress-common-lines -y - dev_list_1.txt
   ```

The result should be something like this:

```
libmtp-2-1.2                                              <
sdb                                                       <
serial                                                    <
sg2                                                       <
ttyACM0                                                   <
```

Or even monitor for change

> ```
> while sleep 1 ; do clear ; ls /dev/ | diff --suppress-common-lines -y
> dev_list_1.txt ; done
> ```

### udev monitor

Launch `sudo udevadm monitor -u` then plug the device.

Answer (score 30):

Here is a quick method . After plugging in USB cable, you just issue:

> dmesg | grep tty

This will output the tty devices detected by kernel, in the order that they were detected and with a time stamp.