# How to check what devices are conncted to serial port

Tags: usb, devices, serial-port

When I am trying to program my Arduino and try to flash the code, I get outputs like

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

This is because the flashing tool does not recognize the USB serial port.

How can I check my devices connected to serial ports, so that I can change the COM port setting of the Arduino flashing tool?

Comment: Look over there: http://askubuntu.com/q/398941/367990

Answer (score 0):

type in terminal "hwinfo --short"
It might tell you to run "sudo apt install hwinfo" Do that its small.
Here the last returning line says"/dev/ttyUSB0  Prolific PL2303 Serial Port" telling me my usb serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0. It tells you everything about everything including its name and port that is connected to your system.